# Unparsable Date despite perfect format

Tags: java, date, intellij-idea, junit, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse a date departureTime:

```
String departureTime2, departureTime;
departureTime2 = departureTime = "2018-01-01 11:11:11.1";
```

Using the JUnit when method

```
when(bookingController.booking( departureTime, departureTime2).thenAnswer(new Answer<MockHttpSession>()
        {
             @Override
             public MockHttpSession answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable
             {
                 Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                 return (MockHttpSession) args[0];
             }
        });
```

My booking method in BookingController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bookingsingle", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String bookingSingle(@RequestParam String departureTime,..)'
```

formats the date using

```
Date departureTimeAsDate = null;

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss.S", Locale.ENGLISH);
    try { departureTimeAsDate =  df.parse(departureTime); } catch (ParseException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

However I receive the error

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-01-01 11:11:11.1"
```

The date appears to be in the perfect format, and upon using the same code in a Java fiddle tool it compiles, however in intellij it runs into the error. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I believe the problem may lie somewhere in the passing of the String in the when() method. Note that booking() has many irrelevant parameters I have excluded.

Comment: kk is used for 24 hour time and is perfectly valid

Comment: The capital S is milliseconds, but you're trying to use it as tenths.  You probably need .SSS.  I don't think there's a way to parse single digit tenths with SimpleDateFormat

Comment: It works fine in my IDEA version. No exceptions raised. What are the JDK and IDEA versions?

Comment: Please see my edit, I believe the problem may be coming from JUnits when() method doing something strange. In the live version the date "2018-12-18 18:25:00.0" works fine and is formatted correctly. I am using JDK 1.8 and IDEA 2017.1.2

Comment: Are 100% sure that the string you passed in the method is exactly like you described?

Comment: Please post a real [mcve] with compileable, runnable code. It is not clear from your description what you are actually doing in your code.

Comment: Yes that is completely what is written in my code

Comment: Would be nice to see the whole body of your test

Comment: I've added the relevant parts of the test. I can include the whole thing however it is very dense in random variables everywhere.

Comment: Where is the conversion happening? I was able to convert the date

Comment: the conversion happens in the booking controller within the booking() method.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't any issue with the date conversion. Are you passing the right value to your controller?

Comment: I suspect that your strings have hours from 00 through 23. `kk` format pattern letter is for hour from 01 through 24, so if my suspicion is correct, there is a bug waiting for you.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Sorry it is a runtime error, my wording was incorrect. Unfortunately this is for testing only and thus I cannot change the method of formatting the date @OleV.V.

Comment: @NicholasK It is definitely the right value, the same String I am passing is the same string that intellij says cannot be parsed.

Comment: @Riggy did you try to check in the debug that it’s absolutely the same string?

Comment: @EvgenyIgnatik copying and pasting the String in the console producing the error provides the same string as the one being passed: 2018-01-01 11:11:11.1

Comment: @Riggy https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html gives an example with three S for miliseconds HH:mm:ss.SSS Did you try using three S in your pattern?

Comment: @actc I can't change which pattern I use, this is purely for testing. The formatting works correctly, the problem seems to be passing the string through JUnits when() method - something happens to the string that the formatter doesn't like